# Error in Matrices concatenation, inconsistent dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

```
%% INPUT DATA
input_data = [200 10.0 0.0095;                             %C1
              240  7.0 0.0070;                             %C2
              200 11.0 0.0090;                             %C3
              220  8.5 0.0090;                             %C4
              220 10.5 0.0080;                             %C5
              0.0015 0.0014 -0.0001 0.0009 -0.0004         %Power Loss
             ];   
pd=830;  %Power Demand
%%
lambda = input ('Enter initial lambda:')
```

Could anyone help me fix this? I've check the row to column data but still cant fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your 6th row, `power`, contains 5 entries, as opposed to `c1` to `c5`, which contain only three entries. MATLAB doesn't do Swiss cheese; I'd suggest making `power` a separate variable.